# What ships have gone missing or their status is unknown in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

What ships in Star Trek have gone missing by Starfleet/NASA/etc (*USS Voyager* doesn't count) and considered lost to the cosmos? These can include ships that were later discovered, such as NASA's 21st century ship *Charybdis* in TNG:"The Royale" or *USS Jenolan* in TNG:"Relics".

Examples from any of the shows or movies are fair game.

Comment: Bloody loads. A bunch each season x 50 seasons.

Comment: Really? There's that many? I had no idea. I figured the list would be like 10-15.

Comment: Try limiting it to a single show. If it turns out not to be too broad, you can always re-ask.

Comment: Do ones that were exiled then forgotten count? Because then the Botany Bay gets added.

Comment: Well there goes my, "how many times was the deflector dish oddly modified to fix a problem," question.